# collectd server not starting

Tags: nginx, collectd

```
luvpreet@luvpreet-vm:/usr/local$ sudo collectd-server start
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.
/usr/local/bin/collectd-server: 8: /usr/local/bin/collectd-server: [[: not found
-e Server has stopped
```

I have followed this [tutorial](http://www.tecmint.com/install-collectd-and-collectd-web-to-monitor-server-resources-in-linux/2/) . Instead of apache I am using Nginx. 
But

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/collectd-server start
```

is giving me the above output.

What is the problem?

Comment: Shell `-x` debugging output of the script might help, given the shell errors.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run a bash script, but not in bash.